# Create a panel data frame in R - where one of the values within a variable changes through time

Tags: r, panel

Using the following data:

```
id <- c(10420,10740, 12060,12060, 12060)
year <- c(2004, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2006)
y <- c(1,1,1,1,1)
data <- data.frame(id, year, y)
data



 id year y
1 10420 2004 1
2 10740 2002 1
3 12060 2003 1
4 12060 2003 1
5 12060 2006 1
```

I would like to create a panel data with the following structure:

```
datapasta::tribble_paste(paneldata)     
  
 tibble::tribble(
~year,   ~id,    ~y,
 2002, 10420,      0,
 2003, 10420,      0,
 2004, 10420,      1,
 2005, 10420,      1,
 2006, 10420,      1,
 2007, 10420,      1,
 2002, 10740,      1,
 2003, 10740,      1,
 2004, 10740,      1,
 2005, 10740,      1,
 2006, 10740,      1,
 2007, 10740,      1,
 2002, 12060,      0,
 2003, 12060,      2,
 2004, 12060,      2,
 2005, 12060,      2,
 2006, 12060,      3,
 2007, 12060,      3
)
```

I have tried to following code to create the panel dataset above.

```
g <- with(data, expand.grid(year = seq(2002,2007), id= unique(id),y=0)) 
data2 <- rbind(data, g)  
data3 <-aggregate(y ~ year + id, data2, sum)[c("id", "year", "y")]
```

However, the code above does not create the panel data as if fails to do the following: For a particular id & year, the values within the variable y should change if a new observation is present. For example, the values for y with id 12060 will be zero for year 2002 then it will change to a value of 2 in the year 2003 and 2005, and then it will change to a value of 3 for years 2006 to 2007.

Any and all thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you for noticing the typo.

Comment: I have updated the post for the new data.

Comment: If your expected output is correct, then the update might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We expand the rows with `complete` (after doing a group by 'id') by getting the `seq`uence of `min` to `max` + 1 of 'year' for entire data and get the cumulative sum of 'y' after grouping by 'id'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)   
data %>% 
    group_by(id, year) %>% 
    mutate(y = cumsum(y)) %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    filter(!duplicated(year, fromLast = TRUE)) %>% 
    complete(year = min(.$year):(max(.$year) + 1), fill = list(y = 0)) %>% 
    mutate(y = cumsum(y))
# A tibble: 18 x 3
# Groups:   id [3]
#      id  year     y
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 10420  2002     0
# 2 10420  2003     0
# 3 10420  2004     1
# 4 10420  2005     1
# 5 10420  2006     1
# 6 10420  2007     1
# 7 10740  2002     1
# 8 10740  2003     1
# 9 10740  2004     1
#10 10740  2005     1
#11 10740  2006     1
#12 10740  2007     1
#13 12060  2002     0
#14 12060  2003     2
#15 12060  2004     2
#16 12060  2005     2
#17 12060  2006     3
#18 12060  2007     3
```

Comment: @VickyN my code was based on your input example.  Also, as I mentioned in the comments below your post, the expected output seems to have some typo for certain elements.  If you can update your post with a new example and correct expected output, it would be easier to understand the issue. thanks

Comment: Code does not work if the variable y has multiple observations with the same id & year, the code above repeats the year such as displayed in the example below. New input: `id <- c( 12060, 12060, 12060)
year <- c( 2003, 2003, 2006)
y <- c(1,1,1)
data <- data.frame(id, year, y))` Then the output using your codes for observation 12060 will be: `  1 12060  2003     1
2 12060  2003     2
3 12060  2004     2
4 12060  2005     2` Any suggestion, on how to take into account this situation for creating the panel dataset?

Comment: I have updated the post with the correct output. It is now the same output that I provided in example in the comment. I still get the year 2003 repeated for id 12060. I also tried your suggestion ["If there are more than one row for the 'id' column, we can do a group_by step before the complete"], but I still get the year 2003 repeated. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In base R, using `expand.grid` you can do :

```
#Create all combinations of `id` and `year`
g <- with(data, expand.grid(id= unique(id), year = seq(2002,2007))) 
#Merge `g` with `data`
data2 <- merge(g, data, all.x = TRUE)
#Replace NA with 0
data2$y[is.na(data2$y)] <- 0
#Increment the value by 1 for each `y` value by `id`.
data2$y <- with(data2, ave(y, id, FUN = cumsum))
```